# django, examples of using a callable for choices in forms.ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, choicefield

In Django documentation, it says that the choices= parameter for forms.ChoiceField can be a callable. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/
Anyone there that can give me an example of how that would look like?
Can't find any more about it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean that it can accept a function (*or something that can be called, hence the name*) that should return values that it wants. Here's a quick rough example:

```
def callableForChoices():
    return [("Value1", "Name1"), ("Value2", "Name2"), ("Value3", "Name3")]

forms.ChoiceField(choices=callableForChoices)
```

This is usually used when you need to dynamically build the choices.

Comment: yes, exactly what I am trying to do. But do you know if I can cal a function from outside of forms.py?

Comment: Absolutely. Just import it and use it as you would any other.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example I can think of:

```
DAY_CHOICES = (
    ('2016-01-02', 'Today'),
    ('2016-01-01', 'Yesterday'),
)

forms.ChoiceField(choices=DAY_CHOICES)
```

Of course, it's not desirable that these are static values. So, a callable is the best alternative here:

```
def get_days():
    return (
        (date.today(), 'Today'),
        (date.today() - timedelta(1), 'Yesterday'),
    )

forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_days)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be possible to call a function from outside of forms.py?

Comment: Sure, just import it from another module.